# Lombok builder methods return the instance of the class itself instead of returning builder class

Tags: java, lombok

I have a class `User`

```
public class User {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int age;

    public User withFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        return this;
    }

    public User withLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
        return this;
    }

    public User withAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
        return this;
    }
}
```

So I can initialize it use `User user = new User().withFirstName("Tom").withAge(30);`, and after `user` is initialized, I can still modify it by `user.withLastName("Bob").withAge(31);`.

How can I leverage Lombok to save the "withXXX" methods? @Builder is not designed for this use case.

Comment: Builder's designed for exactly this use case, you just write it slightly differently: `User.builder().firstName("Tom").age(30).build();`

Comment: @jonrsharpe But once user is built, I'm not able to modify it with same manner, say `user.firstName("foo2").age(23)` is not possible.

Comment: That's right, builder is a creation pattern. What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I edited the description a little, after `user` is initialized, I can still modify it by `user.lastName("Bob").age(31);`

Comment: Why not call setters at that point?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Data
@Builder
@Accessors(fluent = true) // <— This is what you want
public class User {
    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;
    private final int age;
}
```

Then to use:

```
User user = User.builder()
    .firstName("foo")
    .lastName("bar")
    .age(22)
    .build();
```

And later:

```
user.setFirstName("baz").setAge(23); // fluent setters
```

Note how `User` can be made immutable (best practice) by making all fields `final`. If you want mutability, remove `final` keywords.

Comment: But once user is built, I'm not able to modify it with same manner, say `user.firstName("foo2").age(23)` is not possible.

Comment: @coderz then remove `final` keywords. `@Data` gives you setters.

Comment: @coderz Builders are used to make classes immutable. if you need mutability, add just `@Getter` and `@Setter` annotations. And even better not use lombok:

Comment: @Bohemian `@Accessors(fluent = true)` is exactly what I want, it works! Can you edit your answer so that I accept it?